# What is the Query for below scenario

Tags: sql

The Universal Market Corp. has organized its operations using the database schema
described here. The customers listed are themselves retail businesses that order large
quantities of various products from the universal Market Corp. for resale. Distinct
customers in the customers table are uniquely identified by values in the cid (customer
identifier) column. Customers call in the orders to agents (uniquely identified by the aid
value in the agents table). Each time an order is placed, a new row is inserted in the
orders table, uniquely identified by an ordno value.

Tables schema:-

```
Customers (cid, cname, city, discount)

Agents (aid, aname, city, percent)

Products (pid, pname, city, quantity, price)

Orders (ordno, month, cid, aid, pid, qty, dollars)
```

Based on the schema shown above, answer the following queries.

1. Get pnames and pids of products that are stored in the same city as one of the agents
   who sold these products
2. Get pids of products ordered by all customers with any orders placed through agent
   ‘a03’

Comment: I've never heard of Universal Market Corp.  This sounds a lot like homework.  What have you attempted?

Comment: Thanks for reply Gordon, Yes i tried lots but unable to solve it. can you please help by providing some hint to solve it

Comment: You may pass the assignment but will not learn from giving you a direct solution. I suggest posting your attempt at a query, which didn't work and let us point out where it has gone wrong.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about doing the OPs homework for him and shows no attempt to solve the problem himself

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried to write the queries in an easily comprehensible form (ignoring performance).

**1:**

```
SELECT pname, pid
FROM   Products
WHERE  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   Orders
           INNER JOIN Agents ON Agents.aid = Orders.aid
    WHERE  Orders.pid = Products.pid
           Agents.city = Products.city
)
```

This means the following: list all products for which there is a corresponding (first condition) order taken by an agent in the city of the product (second condition).

---

**2:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Orders.pid
FROM   Orders
WHERE  Orders.cid IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT OrdersThroughA03.cid
    FROM   Orders AS OrdersThroughA03
    WHERE  OrdersThroughA03.aid = 'a03'
)
```

This query first gets all customers who had an order through *a03* (in parentheses), then it lists all the different products (`DISTINCT` means it will show each product only once) ordered by these people. I added a table alias (`OrdersThroughA03`) for `Orders` in the inner query to avoid using ambiguous column names.